# WritePixels not working inside dispatch timer

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, bitmap

I'm trying to create code that uses a timer to reveal a bitmap image pixel by pixel.  (Eventually, I want to reveal one color at a time, but starting here as a test.)  I can get the code to work outside of the timer but when I try to do inside the tick event the writeable bitmap is not updating for me.  What's weird is that the code works fine for a colleague!  I've tried retargeting to various .NET versions to no avail.  Also, when I move the declaration of the writeable bitmap inside the tick event, it will update, but I don't get the behavior I'm looking for (redraws from scratch every time rather than revealing an additional pixel.)  Any help appreciated.

Here is timer tick event code. `targetBitmap` is a declared as a public writeable bitmap. `pixels1d` is a one dimensional array that contains the image to be revealed.

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Calculate the current pixel's position
    int x = pixelIndex % 100;
    int y = pixelIndex / 100;

    // Update writeable bitmap pixel with image.
    Int32Rect rect1 = new Int32Rect(x,y, 1, 1);            
    targetBitmap.WritePixels(rect1, pixels1d, stride, 0,0);
    targetControl.Source = targetBitmap;

    // Increment the pixel index for the next iteration
    pixelIndex++;

    // Check if all pixels have been revealed
    if (pixelIndex >= 100 * 100 * 4)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: How often is this firing? Have you considered animating an opacitymask?

Comment: Thanks for the thought, Andy, that was going to be my next strategy if I couldnt get this to work.  Haven't decided on freq yet, but have been testing at 100ms.